# Coldfusion inserting db record and downloading file using Ajax

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

Im trying to create a button that when clicked inserts a record into the database and then downloads a file. I'm trying to do this via Ajax, the file download works but it isn't inserting the record in the db.

**Trigger**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="downloadFile1()">Download</button>
```

**Script**

```
function downloadFile1(){
var file1 = 'https://example.com/files/myfile.zip'; 

    $.ajax({
        TYPE: "POST",
        URL: "components.cfc?method=DownloadFile1",
        data: {fileId : 3},
        success: function() {
                window.location = file1;
        }
    });
}   

</script>
```

Components.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cffunction name="DownloadFile1" access="remote" returntype="string"> 
 <cfcontent type="text/html">
    <CFQUERY NAME="i">
        INSERT into t_terms
        (bid, fildid)
        VALUES
        (
        <cfqueryparam value="#session.busid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#url.fileID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">)
    </CFQUERY>
</cffunction>
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: What happens when you run that function using ColdFusion only?

Comment: There is a closing ) missing in the sql query. Cfqueryparam doesn't require closing tags either.

Comment: At the beginning of your function add <cfcontent type="text/html">. Then on your browser, open the web development tools and click the network tab. Then click the button and look at the call to components.cfc. This will output the error for you. Also, I see at least 2 syntax error with your query: 1) Don't close  </cfqueryparam>; 2) You are missing the closing ")" at the the of the query.

Comment: @JackPilowsky Ive edited the code above) and still no joy. I cant seem to see a call to the component.cfc in the network tab.

Comment: When I run the compontent on its own it works fine.

Comment: 1. Check the browser console. Maybe you have a javascript issue. 2. If the component works fine when hit independently, there must be a problem with the call itself. The fieldID must not be getting passed on as a url param,  specially since you are making a post request. Try changing it to GET and/or moving it into the URL itself.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jack said above, since you're doing a POST and not a GET, instead of looking in the URL scope, try looking in the "FORM" scope.

```
 <cfqueryparam value="#form.fileID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
```

Or, you could just look for "fileID". If it is being passed in, your query will work. If not, it will throw an error.

```
<cfqueryparam value="#fileID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
```

Comment: (Typo Edit) True, but .. the function should not be referencing either URL or FORM. Any value(s) required by the function should be defined as arguments. RE: *Or, you could just look for "fileID"* Technically, yes .. but you should not. It is possible for the same variable name to exist in multiple scopes. So you should always scope variables, to avoid unexpected results -  especially within functions.